# How to Eliminate Extra Spaces of a Page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, space

For my webpage https://www.datanumen.com/access-repair/index.htm , when opening it in FireFox or IE, then the display is OK, as below:

[image]

However, when opening in Chrome, then in the left panel, there will be too many spaces between "DATANUMEN" and "ACCESS", as below:

[image]

That looks very strange. I try to change the alignment of the text to "left", but that does not work at all. See https://www.datanumen.com/access-repair/index2.htm .

How to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I tried in Chrome and IE and they both looked like the first image you posted. Check to see if you've zoomed in on Chrome, or maybe try opening it in an incognito window to see if one of your extensions is messing with it. The code looks like there shouldn't. You do have a text-align: justify css rule that is causing the weird spacing. If you removed that rule, the word access should appear with normal spacing next to datanumen but repair will still be on the next line.

Comment: @kilkfoe, THank you very much for  your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://www.datanumen.com/css/css.css on line 57, you have `text-align: justify;` applying to `.txt11`. When I disable that rule, it looks fine. Presumably, it's overriding whatever you tried to do to set it to left alignment. See if removing that rule fixes the problem for you.